# Como indico en GITEA que un usuario no puede subir a la master de un repositorio

Tags: git, repositorio

Hemos implantado Gitea Versión: 1.13.0 en la empresa y hemos creado un repositorio en el que estamos trabajando varias personas.
Aunque hemos procedimentado que solo un par de miembros del equipo (QA) suban los cambios a la master, me gustaría saber si esto se puede configurar y como.

¿Podemos configurar GITEA para que el resto de miembros no puedan subir a la master?